# xml layout design with coloured background

Tags: android-layout

I have to enter the details in the username field with autocomplete text view,after getting the correct username the keypad should be closed automatically ,i wrote the code until getting the username with keypad & i am facing trouble to write the code for the keypad to be closed automatically ,please help me with this

Comment: Try asking at http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very poorly written, and the title is unrelated.

Here's another stackoverflow answer that goes over how to manually dismiss the android soft-input keyboard.

[Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)